# Bat File to Delete sql database

Tags: sql, database, batch-file, access-denied

I am able to delete files/folders through the bat file fine, the problem comes when i need to delete old mdf and ldf files.

I get access denied error message.

Is there a way to overcome this in the bat file? without having to open sql managment studio 2008 and delete them there?

Things to note:
At the start I do not specificly know what the database is called, just it's location (c:\sql)

Comment: I am not sure but you have to stop the service for sqlserver first, because the sql server preventing the erase of database files.

Comment: wait, you want to delete a existing database? You can create a script which takes your database offline and than deletes

Comment: DROP DATABASE will remove the files. Deleting the files when SQL is stopped makes it suspect/offline. What are you *really* trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sqlcmd in a batch file to drop the database. Something like this:

```
sqlcmd -s dbserver -u username -p password -q "DROP DATABASE databasename"
```

Then you can delete the related mdf and ldf files.

Comment: Thanks! That does indeed delete it, I did the following: 

net stop mssqlserver /y /Y

cd C:\sql

del * /S /Q

rmdir /S /Q "C:\sql\"

net start mssqlserver 


However the database "name" is still listed in ms sql man when i reopen the program? -more of an irritation, but would like to remove that too?

Comment: oh wait, you need to drop the database with sqlcmd first

Comment: That exposes the username & password!
Is there a way to use the login credential instead?

Comment: @ShloEmi you can use the -E (use trusted connection) switch instead of username and password and it will use your windows credentials. See docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

This batch file drops a database even it is being used.
It asks the database name to drop.

```
@echo off

set /p dbName= "Enter your database name to drop: " 

echo Setting to single-user mode
sqlcmd -Q "ALTER DATABASE [%dbName%] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"

echo Dropping...
sqlcmd -Q "drop database %dbName%"

echo Completed.

pause
```

[image]